# Insert string with script tag with javascript code into the DOM

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a string which contains html `script` tag which contains some javascript code. I receive that code from another server via `websocket`.

That string contains some javascript code which performs some changes to the DOM. so I want to evaluate that string. I know that The [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string. But when I evaluate that string I'm getting some escaping error.

Is there any way to append string with javascript code into the DOM and perform the evaluation of that piece of code at the time of their insertion into the DOM.

So consider I have a variable `chain` like bellow

```
let chain = "<script>console.log('test')</script>";
```

I want to append that string which is a representation of a html script tag into the DOM and I want that to be evaluate at the same time it's inserted into the DOM. After that I'll expect to have some log into the browser console.

Comment: If you remove `<script>` and `</script>` from the string you should be able to just use `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

**Note**: I had to change the closing tags in the string from `</script>` to `<\/script>` to make the code snippet work on SO:

```js
let chain = "<script>console.log('Test')<\/script>";
let code = chain.replace('<script>','').replace('<\/script>','')

let script = document.createElement('script')
script.onload = eval(code)

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to perform `eval` on the string you're receiving, you need to strip the tags and `eval` the new string.

The following snippet should work fine for your basic requirements. Just remember that `eval` is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!).

```js
let chain = "<script>console.log('test')<\/script>";
let code = chain.replaceAll(/<\/?[^<>]*>/g, "");
console.log(chain, code);
eval(code);
```